# Lodash the timer of debounce function doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I try to use _.debounce function of lodash, like this:

```
var count = 0;
var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(() => console.log('debounce'), 500);
var timer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('setInterval');
  count++;
  if (count === 505) {clearInterval(timer);}
}, 1);
debouncedFunction();
```

The issue is: after timer count to 127, the debounce function will be trigger while I expected it should be triggered after the timer count to 500.
I don't know why any idea for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval`'s timing is not perfectly accurate. Amounts under 5-10 milliseconds are not very reliable. See the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers) on the issue:

> This API does not guarantee that timers will run exactly on schedule. Delays due to CPU load, other tasks, etc, are to be expected.

Even in optimum conditions, timeouts and intervals probably shouldn't be trusted to be accurate under 10 milliseconds.

10 milliseconds works OK-ish:

```js
// Give the browser time to finish initial load
setTimeout(() => {
  var count = 0;
  var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(() => console.log('debounce'), 500);
  var timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('setInterval', count);
    count += 10;
    if (count === 510) {clearInterval(timer);}
  }, 10);
  debouncedFunction();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

(`debounce` runs at around when 430 is logged, for me)

20 milliseconds works even better (460 or 480):

```js
// Give the browser time to finish initial load
setTimeout(() => {
  var count = 0;
  var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(() => console.log('debounce'), 500);
  var timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('setInterval', count);
    count += 20;
    if (count === 520) {clearInterval(timer);}
  }, 20);
  debouncedFunction();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This isn't an issue with Lodash, this is an issue with timeouts being imprecise.

For more precise timing, run an interval frequently, and check the millisecond difference from the beginning of the interval with `performance.now()` (or maybe `Date.now()`):

```js
// Give the browser time to finish initial load
setTimeout(() => {
  const initial = performance.now();
  var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(() => console.log('debounce'), 500);
  var timer = setInterval(() => {
    const diff = performance.now() - initial;
    console.log('setInterval', diff);
    if (diff >= 520) {clearInterval(timer);}
  });
  debouncedFunction();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```